# Typo3 TCA custom table

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have this situation, I have one offer, and that offer have n number of dates, and n number of options. So I have two additional tables for offer. And third one, which is a price, but price depends of date, and offer. And it is like this:

```
|         |  date 1  |  date 2  |  date 3  |
| offer 1 | price 11 | price 12 | price 13 |
| offer 2 | price 21 | price 22 | price 23 |
| offer 3 | price 31 | price 32 | price 33 |
```

Is there any way to create TCA custom field to insert all of this Price values at once?
So, basically I need one table with input fields and to store also uid of date and offer in it as reference.

Answer (score 0):

Make more than one table... Tables with dynamic col count are horrible bad to maintain.

Table Offer:

```
uid | Name    | Desc
1   | offer1  | This is some cool shit
2   | offer2  | dsadsad
3   | offer3  | sdadsdsadsada
```

Table Date:

```
uid | date
1   | 12.02.2014
2   | 12.03.2014
3   | 20.03.2014
```

Table Prices:

```
uid | date | offer | price
1   |    1 |     1 | price11
2   |    1 |     2 | price21
3   |    1 |     3 | price31
4   |    2 |     1 | price12
5   |    2 |     2 | price22
6   |    2 |     3 | price32
7   |    3 |     1 | price13
8   |    3 |     2 | price23
9   |    3 |     3 | price33
```

And then its straight forward...

Comment: But he says he has the data in separate tables. He's just asking how to edit it all at once while maintaining the relations.